# SQL parent child hierarchy level columns

Tags: sql

I need to transform this:

| PositionID | ReportsToID |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B | A |
| C | B |
| D | C |
| E | D |

Into this:

| PositionID | ReportsToID | Level 1 ID | Level 2 ID | Level 3 ID | Level 4 ID | Level 5 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | A |  |  |  |  |
| B | A | A | B |  |  |  |
| C | B | A | B | C |  |  |
| D | C | A | B | C | D |  |
| E | D | A | B | C | D | E |

I am a complete SQL novice and no idea how to tackle this...  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Googling for code that has done this already - have not found any

Comment: A query cannot produce a dynamic number of columns. Do you know for sure there are 5 levels at the most? It that's the case you can join the table 5 times with itself. Otherwise you can produce a single column with the whole branch using a recursive CTE.

Comment: @TheImpaler ah ok.  Join it onto itself, nice, thanks!

Comment: @TheImpaler thought that would be easy, but I am a bit stumped on the logic of this... any chance you can help?

I will have 10 levels in the data set, here are the columns names with:
SELECT DISTINCT m.[t101f130_reports_to_position] as PosID
    ,lvl1.[t101f005_position_no] as CanAccess
  FROM [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t101_position] m
  LEFT JOIN [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t101_position] lvl1
  ON m.[t101f130_reports_to_position] = lvl1.[t101f130_reports_to_position]

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write a generic solution for unlimited levels. It's possible to walk all the levels using a recursive CTE.

For example:

```
with recursive 
n as (
  select position_id, reports_to_id, reports_to_id as rti,
    cast(position_id as varchar) as pt 
  from t
 union all
  select n.position_id, n.reports_to_id, t.reports_to_id, 
    t.position_id || ' < ' || n.pt
  from n
  join t on n.rti = t.position_id
)
select position_id, reports_to_id, pt from n where rti is null
```

Result:

```
 position_id  reports_to_id  pt                
 ------------ -------------- ----------------- 
 A            null           A                 
 B            A              A < B             
 C            B              A < B < C         
 D            C              A < B < C < D     
 E            D              A < B < C < D < E
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2r_DtKAt).

If you need a static solution with a specific number of columns, it can be done with multiple unioned-queries, each one with an increasing number of joins.